# How do I know which child class a Django model object is when selected through the parent class?

Tags: django, django-models, python-2.6, django-1.3

I have a main `Event` class, and four event types. Each of them is a subclass of (at least) `Event`. On an event's detail page, I am adding a link back to the admin interface for a given event to save the time of searching in the admin. Unfortunately, regardless of child class, the events are selected from the parent `Event` class. My solution to this problem was to duck type, which I find to be absolutely awful in this instance. **I am hoping there is a more elegant and easy-to-maintain solution to my problem.**

Model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    ...

class ListedEvent(Event):
    ....

class RSVPEvent(Event):
    ....

class TicketedEvent(Event):
    ....

class TicketedConcert(TicketedEvent):
    ....
```

To see event details, the URL passes a venue slug and event name slug. This is enough info to isolate a single event from the parent `Event` model across all the child events. It also lets me keep the event type out of the URL, making them simpler and more friendly.

```
@render_to('events/event_details.html')
def event_details(request, venue, slug):
    """
    Detail view of an event.
    """
    try:
        event = Event.objects.select_related(
            'listedevent',
            'rsvpevent',
            'ticketedevent',
            'ticketedconcert',
            'venue',
            'sites',
            'dj',
        ).get(
            slug=slug,
            venue__slug=venue,
        )
    except Event.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    return {'event': event}
```

Before I went back and realized that I was using the parent `Event` model, this solution was much more elegant and worked fine in the shell assuming I select an event from its actual model (property of parent class `Event`):

```
@property
def admin_link(self):
    et = self.__class__.__name__.lower()
    # ALWAYS: et == 'event', reverse() fails, returns ''
    return reverse('admin:events_%s_change' % et, args=(self.id,))
```

My current solution (property of parent class `Event`):

```
@property
def admin_link(self):
    duck = None

    try:
        duck = self.ticketedevent.ticketedconcert.artist_name
        return reverse(
            'admin:events_ticketedconcert_change',
            args=(self.id,)
        )
    except:
        pass

    try:
        duck = self.ticketedevent.max_tickets
        return reverse(
            'admin:events_ticketedevent_change',
            args=(self.id,)
        )
    except:
        pass

    try:
        duck = self.rsvpevent.total_rsvp
        return reverse(
            'admin:events_rsvpevent_change',
            args=(self.id,)
        )
    except:
        pass

    try:
        duck = self.listedevent.name
        return reverse(
            'admin:events_listedevent_change',
            args=(self.id,)
        )
    except:
        pass
```

There has to be a simpler, more easy-to-maintain method of finding out which type of event I'm looking at. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929029/how-do-i-access-the-child-classes-of-an-object-in-django-without-knowing-the-nam) [common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735124/django-model-inheritance-query-a-central-table) [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109461/django-model-subclassing-get-the-subclass-by-querying-the-superclass) and still seems to be one of Django's uglier ducklings.

You could at least rearrange for 2 cents of DRY gain:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

@property
def event_type(self):
     for et in ('ticketedevent', 'rsvpevent', 'sillyhatsonlyevent', ...):
         try:
             getattr(self, et)
             return et
         except ObjectDoesNotExist:
             pass

@property
def admin_link(self):
    return reverse('admin:events_%s_change' % self.event_type, args=(self.id,))
```

If you really want to be fancy, you could use `Event.__subclasses__` and generate the list of event types.